# Is this proof correct? Establishing that $|x+y| \geq | |x| - |y| |$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Using that $|a|+|b|\geq|a+b|$
\begin{align}
|-x|+|x+y| \geq |-x+x+y| = |y|\\
|-y|+|x+y| \geq |-y+x+y| = |x|
\end{align}

Substracting $|-x|$ from the first inequality and $|-y|$ from the second:

\begin{align}
|x+y| \geq  |y|-|-x| \\
|x+y| \geq  |x| - |-y| 
\end{align}

Using the fact that if $a \geq b$ and $a \geq -b$ then $a \geq |b|$.

\begin{align}
|x+y| \geq  ||x| - |-y|| = ||x| - |y||
\end{align}

Is the above correct?

Comment: The proof is good!

Comment: Seems good enough!

Comment: Nice work.  See also [Help checking proof of $|x| - |y| \leq |x+y|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507233/help-checking-proof-of-reverse-triangle-inequality-x-y-le-x-y?rq=1)

Comment: Perfect. But I would have typed $|(|x|-|y|)|$ or $|\; |x|-|y|\;|$(etc.) to make it easier to read, and to avoid confusion with the functional-analysis symbol $||z||$ (also written $\|z\|,$ coded as \|z\|). You can use \; and \, to add a little space between  key-strokes.