# Prove using the triangular inequality that: $|a+b| \geq |a| - |b|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

How can I prove using the triangular inequality that:
$$|a+b| \geq |a| - |b|$$

I already proved it by considering all 8 possible scenarios (like a>b and b=0 ... etc) However I couldn’t manage to find the way to prove it only by using the triangular inequality.

Comment: This is the "reverse triangle inequality". See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507233/help-checking-proof-of-reverse-triangle-inequality-x-y-le-x-y) for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: the inequality you wish to prove is equivalent to
$$|a + b| + |-b| \ge |a|.$$

Answer (score 3):

By triangular inequality we have:
$$|a|=|a+b +(-b)|\leq |a+b|+|b|.$$
Thus,
$$|a+b| \geq |a| - |b|.$$